# Completeness of set

Tags: convergence-divergence

Show that the set of bounded continuous functions is complete in the sup-norm.

My work: we want every Cauchy sequence to have a limit in the same set. But I don't understand what we can start with. If we take some Cauchy sequence $||f_n - f_m|| \leq \epsilon$, but we still have no information about its convergence...

Comment: I saw the question, but it starts the solution at a level I don't understand.

Comment: For example, "Since for fixed $x$, $f_n(x)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$" - i don't see why?

Comment: That is a claim in the first proof.

Comment: Is this claim based on a theorem? Where does it come from?

Comment: That is an assumption which is used to prove and simplify the statement.